# Understanding css calc() function

Tags: css

[Heydon Pickering](https://heydonworks.com/article/the-flexbox-holy-albatross/) wrote an article about mimicking container queries. He writes that the container's CSS should be as follows:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  --margin: 1rem;
  --multiplier: calc(40rem - 100%);
  margin: calc(var(--margin) * -1); /* excess margin removed */
}
```

and the container's children's CSS should be:

```
.container > * {
  min-width: calc(33% - (var(--margin) * 2)); /* remove from both sides */
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--multiplier) * 999);
  margin: var(--margin);
}
```

I'm just trying to understand how the `--multiplier` custom property works ie where `40rem - 100%` what is 100% of?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage) in CSS is relative to the parent.
So in this case, the calc is as follow: `40rem - 100% [of the width of the parent]`.

The author explains it in their post:

> the calculated value will be negative if the container is 40rem or more and positive if it's narrower than 40rem.

**Examples:**

- If the parent element is 20rem, the result will be `40rem - 20rem`, so `20rem`;
- If the parent element is 80rem, the result will be `40rem - 80rem`, so `-60rem`;

In the `calc()` function you can actually mix many units (em, vmin, %, px, etc...), in the end they will all be unit of length and thus compatible with each other

Answer (score 1):

The 100% will just be in relation to whatever property the variable is being applied to.

`--multiplier` is just a variable, in this use case it is no different from just typing out its contents where it is being used.

So in this case:

```
flex-basis: calc(var(--multiplier) * 999);
```

is the same as

```
flex-basis: calc(calc(40rem - 100%) * 999);
```

And the 100% is in relation to the `flex-basis` property, and relative to the targets parent. You can read about the effect this has for `flex-basis` specifically in the [flex-basis values section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#values).